# How is Apache mapping files without extensions?

Tags: filesystems, php, apache-http-server, url, rewrite

My local dev setup is mapping things like http://mydomain.dev/testhtmlpage to testhtmlpage.html and http://mydomain.dev/testphppage to testphppage.php. The browser stays on the orginally enter URL. The thing is I didn't configure my machine orginally and although I have a decent handle on it now I can't find where this behaviour is being defined.

I've checked my httpd.conf and the two included areas with no luck.

**My httpd.conf:** http://denishoctor.me/myhttpdconf.xml (view source)

**In Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf:**

```
<IfModule php5_module>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can be caused by a number of things, from rewrite rules to content negotiation. Judging by your `httpd.conf`, the reason in this particular case is because you have Multiviews turned on.

Excerpt from your config:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

Change it to this and restart Apache:

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

Comment: Thats was it! Thank you. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#multiviews

Comment: @DenisHoctor you're most welcome :)